# WordNet: getting the most reasonable definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordnet

I'm using Wordnet [Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet) with WordNet [wordnet-defaultdb](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet-defaultdb) in a Rails application. Sometimes this code gives meaningless definitions like this:

```
require 'wordnet'
lex = WordNet::Lexicon.new
synset = lex[:brown]
synset.definition #=> "a university in Rhode Island"
```

Or it can define 'second' as "the fielding position of the player on a baseball team who is stationed near the second of the bases in the infield".

Is there a way to sort definitions by usage and get the most relevant ('brown' as a color and 'second' as numeral or as a unit of time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lookup_synsets`](http://deveiate.org/code/ruby-wordnet/WordNet/Lexicon.html#method-i-lookup_synsets) to return all synsets instead of just the first.

```
lex.lookup_synsets( :brown )
```

The WordNet data files come with a [`cntlist`](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/cntlist.5WN.html) which lists the number of times "each tagged sense occurs in a semantic concordance" so the common terms have the highest count. Your two example requirements would be the top result using this count.

The tag count is put into the `sense` table in the database but it doesn't look like the WordNet gem provides an interface to the data so you can use the `sequel` methods to access it.

```
lex.lookup_synsets( :brown ).each do |s|    
  printf "%5d: %s\n", WordNet::Sense.select( :tagcount ).where( :synsetid=>s.synsetid ).first.tagcount, s.definition
end
```

Or if you can lookup the `:wordid` for your word then you can get the `:synsetid` with the highest tag count in a single query:

```
WordNet::Sense.select( :synsetid ).where( :wordid => 17745 ).reverse( :tagcount ).limit( 1 ).first.synsetid
```

There's probably going to be times when this doesn't help you too, where there are tied top counts or no counts at all.